# How to delete all SQLite data from android studio?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I'm trying to delete all data from an SQLite database when a user presses a button. But the app keeps crashing when I press the remove button. I tried using the delete method. But the result is same

Here is my reset method on DatabaseHelper:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
   
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("Create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,MAIL TEXT,PASS TEXT);");
}
public void reset () {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

On Main Activity:

```
clearData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alart=new AlertDialog.Builder(Home.this);
            alart.setTitle("Are you sure?");
            alart.setMessage("Are you sure want to clear all your data?");
            alart.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    mydb.reset();  // mydb is a DatabaseHelper obj

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Removed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            alart.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog a = alart.create();
            a.show();
        }
    });
```

[Error Message sshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roB9K.png)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the error message and the onCreate() method.

Comment: Sharing the stacktrace would also be helpful to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work.

`db.delete("TABLE_NAME", null, null);`

Comment: can you share the full void method that I should write on the DataBaseHelper class?

Comment: It's pre written method by SQLite  in SQLiteDatabase.class so no need of writing void class in your helper class you just need to open you Database Ex: `db = databasehelpe.getWriteableDatabase();`

Answer (score 1):

try this to delete data only:

```
public void cleardata(String TABLE_NAME) {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String clearDBQuery = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(clearDBQuery);
}
```